# Recibir Notificacion

Tags: android

Desde una App envio una notificacion a todos los que tienen instalado otra app.

Todo funciona bien en algunos telefonos en otros sale un error al recibir la notificacion es esta linea:

```
public class RecibirNotificaciones extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onNewToken(@NonNull String token) {
    super.onNewToken( token );
    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("enviaratodos").addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
    });
    /*FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("enviaratodos").addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
        }
    });*/
}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived( remoteMessage );

    String from = remoteMessage.getFrom();

    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0 ) {
        String titulo  = remoteMessage.getData().get("titulo");
        String detalle  = remoteMessage.getData().get("detalle");
        mayorqueoreo (titulo, detalle);
    }

}

private void mayorqueoreo(String titulo, String detalle) {
    String id = "mensaje";
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService( Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE );
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder( this, id );
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel( id, "iesemeritaaugusta", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH  );
        notificationChannel.setShowBadge(true);
        assert notificationManager != null;
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel( notificationChannel );
    }
    builder.setAutoCancel( true )
            .setWhen( System.currentTimeMillis() )
            .setContentTitle( titulo )
            .setSmallIcon( R.mipmap.ic_launcher )
            .setContentText( detalle )
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setContentIntent( clicknoti() )
            .setContentInfo( "iesemeritaaugusta" );


    Random random = new Random( );
    int idNotify = random.nextInt(8000);
    assert notificationManager != null;
    notificationManager.notify( idNotify, builder.build() );
}

public PendingIntent clicknoti() {
    Intent intent = new Intent( getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class );
    intent.putExtra( "color", "rojo" );
    intent.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP  | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    return PendingIntent.getActivity( RecibirNotificaciones.this, 0, intent, 0);
}
```

}

En la linea:

```
return PendingIntent.getActivity( RecibirNotificaciones.this, 0, intent, 0);
```

Si comento la linea:`.setContentIntent( clicknoti() )`

Salta la notificacion pero no se queda grabada en el movil y al cabo de unos segundo desaparece de la linea de notoficaciones.

¿Como lo puedo solucionar?

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error?, es importante agregarlo a tus preguntas, por otro lado, las notificaciones no desaparecen una vez desplegadas.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo he solucionado.

El problema radica en las versiones nuevas de los moviles  y aunque funcionen en las versiones antiguas en las más recientes no funcionan.

Hay que añadir un nuevo permiso al AndroidManifest.xml que es

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
```

y ademas es ogligatorio poner en la clase  RecibirNoticicaciones.java (Puesta mas arriba) el bit MUTABLE

```
return PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);
```

Despues de todo esto lo unico es que el usuario debe de activar las Notificaciones en su App. Ya vere como lo realizo automaticamente si se puede.

Ver : https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/changes/notification-permission?hl=es-419